# Mensagem final nas respostas

Tags: debate, respostas

Como eu sempre voto +1 nas perguntas que respondo, estava pensando em inserir uma "assinatura" no final das respostas, algo do tipo:

> Boa pergunta. +1

Isso é bom ou ruim? Infringe alguma norma?

Comment: Não que eu esteja insinuando que seja essa sua intençao, mas pra mim, isso seria uma tentativa de mostrar que voce votou na pergunta e pedir voto na sua resposta como troca. Acho que o voto não precisa ser explicitado, afinal, quando dão negativo ninguém sai dizendo "-1 péssima resposta/pergunta".

Comment: Mas ninguém diz que deu -1 nas respostas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Em alguns casos colocar isto pode ser "orgânico" e acrescentar algo útil, mas fazer por fazer, usar em todos casos me parece mais complicado, até por ser uma [assinatura que é oficialmente não recomendada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Eu respondo um monte de pergunta que não é boa, na verdade quase todas :) Claro que não é tão ruim assim. Tem uma ou outra que até arrependo de responder e já apaguei algumas respostas.

Qualquer coisa que é automático é considerado ruído. Tudo depende de contexto.

Até em comentário eu evito muito usar um +1 porque em geral isso quer dizer "olha eu votei em você, eu sou legal, seja legal comigo", mesmo que a pessoa ache que não é isso. Quando eu coloco é porque merecia +10 ou um contraponto por eu ter criticado algum ponto apesar de ser boa no geral, aí sai algo assim: "eu até dei +1, mas..."

Comment: Isso mesmo. Minha pergunta foi um devaneio tolo. Nada a ver colocar isso nas respostas. Obg!

Answer (score 5):

A forma oficial de recompensar uma pergunta por ser boa é o voto positivo.

O problema da ideia de se dizer ao OP que a pergunta foi boa é só o lugar.

> no final das respostas

*"Boa pergunta, +1"* não é parte de uma resposta, então é ruído. Acho que fica melhor se você disser isso em um comentário.

Comment: Verdade. Eu viajei na maionese. Obg!